# Hold checked items in list view. Searched and searched but no luck or I don't understand

Tags: android, list, listview, checkbox

I am trying to have a checked list retain values when scrolling in a listview and then also until the user has chosen to clear the list. I know that this has been asked many times but every answers I've read over the last two days havn't worked for me or I don't understand enough about what I'm doing to get it right (first thing I've developed). I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction using my actual code please? Or something that will means something to the code I have. Thank you in advance!

Below is my list code:

```
public class ShopList {

    public String RecName;
    public String RecIngredient;

    public ShopList(String recName, String recIng) {
        this.RecName = recName;
        this.RecIngredient = recIng;

    }
}
```

Below is my Custom Adapter:

```
public class ShoppingListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShopList> {
public ShoppingListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ShopList> shoppingLists) {
    super(context, 0, shoppingLists);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    ShopList shopList = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shoppinglist, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvRecName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvRecipeShop);
        holder.tvIngredient = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvIngredShop);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvRecName.setText(shopList.RecName);
    holder.tvIngredient.setText(shopList.RecIngredient);
    holder.tvIngredient.isChecked();

    return convertView;

}
    public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvRecName;
    public CheckedTextView tvIngredient;

}


}
```

And this is the relevant code from my Activity:

```
public void getListData(){

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvShoppingList);

        ArrayList<ShopList> shopListArray = new ArrayList<ShopList>();

        ShoppingListAdapter myAdapter = new ShoppingListAdapter(this, shopListArray);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShoppingList);

        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ShoppingList", null);

        c.moveToFirst();



        while (!c.isAfterLast()){

            String RecName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("RecipeName"));
            String RecIngredient = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("IngredientName"));

            ShopList sL = new ShopList(RecName, RecIngredient);

            myAdapter.add(sL);

            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
}

public void toggle(View v)
{
    CheckedTextView cView = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvIngredShop);
    if (cView.isSelected())
    {
        cView.setSelected(false);
        cView.setChecked(false);

    }
    else {
        cView.setSelected(true);
        cView.setChecked(true);


    }
}

}
```

I still have a checkbox in my layout that I have just made invisible for now while I tried to get a solution trying to mimic what the simple_list_item_multiple_choice does. Can always put it back if need be.

I also understand that my SQL query is not the "correct" way of doing things from what I can gather but as a newbie I could recognise what it was doing and it's worked for me so far.

Thank you for your assistance, this has been bothering me for too long now. Also, sorry that I know it's a repeatedly asked question but I am at a loss. Thanks

UPDATE!!!!

This is the toggle code which is called onClick on the Ingredient CheckedTextView.

```
public void toggle(View v) {
    CheckedTextView cView = (CheckedTextView)         v.findViewById(R.id.tvIngredShop);
    TextView tvRecName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvRecipeShop);
    String recName = tvRecName.getText().toString();
    if (cView.isSelected())
    {
        cView.setSelected(false);
        cView.setChecked(false);
        myDB.execSQL("UPDATE ShoppingList SET isChecked = 0 WHERE RecipeName = '" + recName + "'");


    }
    else {
        cView.setSelected(true);
        cView.setChecked(true);
        myDB.execSQL("UPDATE ShoppingList SET isChecked = 1 WHERE RecipeName = '"+recName+"'");

    }
}
```

I think the null pointer exception is because it can't find the tvRecName textview.

The error is this:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: truckyforall.com.recipeconverterv2, PID: 1933
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at truckyforall.com.recipeconverterv2.AddToShoppingList.toggle(AddToShoppingList.java:180)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Thanks

Comment: In you custom adapter you should probably use `holder.tvIngredient.setChecked(true);` instead of `holder.tvIngredient.isChecked();` ?

Comment: Thanks I had tried that previously but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What exactly happened? You need to set the check box's value at that point. As you can see in in no 2 of Rafals answer. Of course if you only set it to true they will all be checked!

Comment: Sorry what I meant was that when I select an item ie. check the box, the selection doesn't hold when the view is recycled. It checks the first box then when I scroll down the list, the 7th or 8th box is ticked. Same when I untick it. Is that clearer? Thanks

Comment: I guess there is space for 5 or 6 items then? ListView will hold as many items as fit on the screen. Maybe +1 as a buffer. Then it will start to recycle the views when you scroll. So item 1 goes out of the screen and the view for item 1 will be reused on item 7. When you checked item 1 and you don't change the value, then item 7 (which is the recycled item 1) will also be checked....

Comment: Yeah that is what happens, and that is what I'm trying to stop happening. So I need the tick to remain static in the list until unticked or the user clears the list. Every new item added will be unticked or have a value of 0 to begin with. The activity is a shopping list, so as you buy the ingredients you would mark them off the list by checking the box.

Comment: Then you should do exactly like Rafal described it. If you have another problem (`NPE`) try to sort it out. If you can't ask another questions. Don't edit and add other problems. Otherwise your questions will be very hard to look through which will not attract anyone to help you to sort it out...

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Add new field `isChecked` to your `ShopList` class:

```
public class ShopList {

    public String RecName;
    public String RecIngredient;
    public int isChecked;

    public ShopList(String recName, String recIng, int isChecked){
        this.RecName = recName;
        this.RecIngredient = recIng;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
}
```

**2.** When populating `ViewHolder`, in `getView()`, set the `CheckBox` state:

```
holder.tvRecName.setText(shopList.RecName);
holder.tvIngredient.setText(shopList.RecIngredient);
// this is the line that sets your checkbox depending on the value - answering your question in the comment
holder.tvIngredient.setChecked(shopList.isChecked == 0);
```

**3.** Remember to properly save and load this new field from your SQL database, eg. like:

```
int isChecked = c.getInteger(c.getColumnIndex("isChecked"));
ShopList sL = new ShopList(RecName, RecIngredient, isChecked);
```

**4.** When you change the checkbox state, you need to also update your object's `isChecked` value:

```
shopList.isChecked = holder.tvIngredient.isChecked() ? 1 : 0;
```

My advise would be to move the onClick listener into your adapter, so you have easy access to shopList object that is supposed to change.

Comment: Thank you! I have added it in except I don't think SQLite likes Boolean, so I changed it to Integer and when I add the data initially into the table I set isChecked to 0. Though when I pull it back out through my cursor, I'm not sure where to add an if statement to say "if this specific record isChecked == 0 then don't tick the box else if isChecked == 1 then tick the box". Any ideas please?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do I need to add an if statement there? Or is that something I need to do when in onCreate on the activity? At the moment, I am playing with adding the SQL to update the DB value if checked or not but it can't find the TextView that holds the recipe name data. Will update my question to see if you or anyone else can help! Thanks

Comment: also, the checkboxes now, after adding the third line are all showing as ticked by default and the checkbox is changing only after clicking on it twice???

Comment: with the viewholder you are setting all values for each row in your list view. You are already setting `recName` and `recIngredient`. Now you also need to set wehter the checkbox was checked or not! Do edits only when they further explain the original problem - don't introduce new problems. Ask a new question for new problems.

Comment: I added another point to my answer. When you change the state of a CheckBox, you need to also update the `isChecked` field value in your `ShopList` model accordingly. Right now, you need to look into your `toggle()` method carefully, as it's causing you problems.

Comment: My apologies.. as the solution didn't solve the original problem and caused some different problems, I thought it would be appropriate to discuss until I could post a full solution.

Comment: Thanks @RafałZawadzki I really appreciate your help. It turns out my knowledge base doesn't extend as far as adding the onClick listener in the adapter. I can add them find to an Activity I just don't know how to reference things from the Adapter. Unfortunately, I have to go now and won't get a chance to try it properly for a day or so. I will give it a good shot though and I'll get back to you with what happened. Thanks again so much for your help, I know it must be frustrating helping someone with little idea on what they're actually doing.